# JSTL Illegal text inside "c:choose" tag: "<!-- ..."

Tags: jstl

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${somecondition}">
      ...
    </c:when>
    <!-- if not somecondition do otherwise -->
    <c:otherwise>
      ...
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

The above code will throw a jspError, "JSTL Illegal text inside "c:choose" tag: "

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${somecondition}">
      ...
    </c:when>
    <%-- if not somecondition do otherwise --%>
    <c:otherwise>
      ...
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

You can't use < !-- --> comments. 
Thought I would share since I didn't see this on stackoverflow and ran into it today.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-44363

Comment: Note that `<% // comment %>` or `<% /* comment */ %>` are also **not** valid. They are considered as `choose`'s childs during compilation which throw an error.

Comment: That is interesting I am glad I found this early cause that would have taken a lot of time to find if I was being hard headed and trying to debug other areas of the code when it was a comment issue. Thank you for your post.

Comment: FYI: (can't edit the answer) The spec for c:choose says: Constraints
■The body of the <c:choose> action can only contain:
■White spaces
May appear anywhere around the <c:when> and <c:otherwise> subtags.
■1 or more <c:when> actions
Must all appear before <c:otherwise>
■0 or 1 <c:otherwise> action
Must be the last action nested within <c:choose>

Answer (score 0):

While comments would be useful, this constraint is documented in the JSTL spec. For Apache's implementation, it is enforced by a taglib validator: `org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV` (declared in `c.tld`).

Answer (score -1):

HTML comments in between c tags of JSTL core, are invalid.  They must be JSP comments.i.e; <%-- -->

Comment: Unlike on old fashioned forums, on question&answer sites such as Stack Overflow, there's absolutely no need to repeat an already given answer when you agree it. Instead, simply upvote the already given answer. This will save the Internet from undigestably large pages wherein everyone herd-repeats each other upon agreement.